# Nodejs API doesn't work after reboot centos server

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, centos7, pm2

In my centos server, I have an API with node js and I started with pm2. pm2 status is online and It works correctly. but when server reboot, can't connect to the API although pm2 status is online.
I also try start node js like below

```
pm2 start index.js
pm2 startup 
pm2 save
```

but It does not work until I restart pm2 ..
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do [pm2 resurrect](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#manually-resurrect-processes) to start an application after "pm2 saving" it:

```
pm2 resurrect
```

Then put this command in a script file and configure it to run on server reboot. Read this [Q and A](https://superuser.com/questions/309834/how-to-run-a-script-on-centos-linux-startup) for help. Also [in this](https://www.tecmint.com/auto-execute-linux-scripts-during-reboot-or-startup/) article there are some CentOS specific changes that need to be done.

Comment: Hi. I got pm2 logs and see this error . " error onlineTypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string." . and I changed the connection string direct on module export and it fixed. However need to add pm2 resurrect?

Comment: Its needed if you want your app to restart on its own whenever server reboots.